# Cannot see Intellij Idea Palette

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, palette

I got a project which is written by Swing.

I import that project into Intellij Idea 12.

But when I check View -> Tool Windows -> Palette option is disabled.

I am pretty new at Java Swing. (Actually first) I need to add Text Boxes, JPanel or something to that project. And I need to make that as visual by using a GUI tool. But it is disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Palette Tool Window is only visible when a *GUI Designer* form is open in the editor. It is not available (i.e. is not enabled) for standard Java classes, even if that class is or extends a Swing component. To create a form, from the *new* menu (i.e. when you right click or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on a package in the project window or navigator bar, or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to create a new element in the current package) select "GUI Form" or "Dialog".

You can read more about the *Gui Designer* in the help guide.